# Unable to run validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Hey I am trying to validate my form if there's a blank input using javascript, I do know about `require` keyword using HTML but I am really trying to figure out what's wrong in the code I have written?

```
<html>
<body>
  <script> function x (info) {
  if(info.namex.value==" " || info.namex.value == "null")
  {
    alert ("Check again");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
<form method = "post" name = "a" onsubmit = "return x(this)">
  <input type = "text" name = "namex">
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: remove the space from info.namex.value=="".

Comment: What about if I want to run it like `<input type = "submit" value = "submit"> onclick = "return x(this)">`

Comment: @PaulStoner First of all, you close the tag twice. Secondly it would not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have this:

```
if(info.namex.value==" ")
// -------------------^--
```

You don’t check if the string is empty. You check if it has exactly one space character. That empty space between the two quotes is a character and your check requires the input to have it. You check if the user has pressed the spacebar key a single time. To check for an empty string, you should do this:

```
if(info.namex.value=="")
```

However, you can also write it like that:

```
if(!info.namex.value)
```

This will enter the `if` code block when `info.namex.value` is falsy. A falsy value is `0`, `undefined`, `null` *an empty string* `""` and more. Read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

---

Also, as Krzysztof Janiszewski said, you have to remove the quotes from `null`. If you put it in quotes, you don’t compare to the *value* `null`, you compare to a string with contents of "null". I.E. you check if the user typed "null" in the input field.

`null`: the primitive value `null`
`"null"`: string with contents "n", "u", "l" and "l"

Read more about `null` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).

---

What you probably need, though, is the following:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    function x(info) {
      if (!info.namex.value.match(/\S/)) {
        alert("Check again");
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <form method="post" name="a" onsubmit="return x(this)">
    <input type="text" name="namex">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In this line:

```
!info.namex.value.match(/\S/)
```

This is regex `/\S/` and it will match any non-whitespace character. The alert will be shown if only a non-whitespace character is *not* present in the input. This means that any combination of whitespace will not make it. If you have `" "` or `"     "` - that is just whitespace and not any legitimate input. You probably don’t want that. If the string is empty `""`, there is still no non-whitespace character, so the alert is still shown.

The only way to pass the check is if you have a "visible" symbol anywhere in the input. If you only have spaces, tabs, newlines - those are whitespace. Your check requires at least one letter, number, symbol - anything *but* those whitespace characters.

Learn more about regex [here](https://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `function` has not complete set of validations/conditions and it maybe goes wrong , because you are checking being `empty` of `namex` field with 2 conditions and one of them is "" [space].

If you are okay with `jquery` , I suggest [jqueryValidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) , it is easy to use and has complete set of validations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an input is empty then I suggest doing this:

```
const x = (info) => {
  if (!info.namex.value.trim().length) {
    alert ("Check again");

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, if you want to check if variable is equal to `null` do not surround `null` with any kind of quotes.

**Secondly**, if you check if variable is an empty string do not put space inside of double quotes `""`

Except for that, your code is fine.

**Here is a working example**

```js
function x(info) {
  if (info.namex.value == "" || info.namex.value == null) {
    alert("Check again");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="a" onsubmit="return x(this)">
  <input type="text" name="namex">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```